# How can I change the angle of a laser without mechanical aid

Tags: visible-light, laser

I'm trying to figure out a way I can bend  change the angle of the beam coming from a cheap laser diode or laser pointer on the fly. One thought I had was a small prism or mirror that is attached to a micro servo, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this without using any moving parts. I know that a cathode tube works somewhat in this manner, but since light does have charge, I'm sure this would not work. Any help would be great.

Comment: It might not be in your budget but you can use an [acousto-optic modulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acousto-optic_modulator).

Comment: ditto a [spatial light modulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_light_modulator) with phase control